# How to understand 1 Corinthians 13:2 in light of Genesis 15:6 and Hebrews 11:6?

Tags: genesis, 1-corinthians, hebrews, faith

According to 1 Corinthians 13 it seems other gifts combined with faith cannot qualify one to be recognized as pleasing to God outside of love.

1 Corinthians 13:1-2 ESV

> 13 If I speak in the tongues of men and of angels, but have not love, I am a noisy gong or a clanging cymbal. 2 And if I have prophetic powers, and understand all mysteries and all knowledge, and ***if I have all faith, so as to remove mountains, but have not love, I am nothing***.

But according to Genesis Abraham was accredited with righteousness for believing(faith) God's promises without any reference to issues of love.

Genesis 15:6 ESV

> ***6 And he believed the Lord, and he counted it to him as righteousness***.

Even the author of Hebrews seems to reiterate the same position of faith that you can be pleasing to God if you walk in faith

Hebrews 11:6 ESV

> ***6 And without faith it is impossible to please him***, for whoever would draw near to God must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who seek him.

How then do we understand the above texts

Comment: See Galatians 5:6.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that we need the trio of Christian virtues:

> 1 Cor 13:13 - And now these three remain: **faith, hope, and love**; but
> the greatest of these is love.

These same three essential virtues are repeated elsewhere as well:

- Col 1:5 - the **faith and love** proceeding from the **hope** stored up for you in heaven, of which you have already heard in the word of truth, the gospel
- 1 Thess 1:3 - remembering before our God and Father your work of **faith** and unceasing labor of **love**, and the endurance of the **hope** of our Lord Jesus Christ,
- 1 Thess 5:8 - But since we belong to the day, let us be sober, putting on the breastplate of **faith and love**, and the helmet of our **hope** of salvation.

A moment's reflection reveals that it is these three virtues, given as a gift of God, that make us distinctly human.  All are essential because, without any one of them we cease to be human:

- without hope, a person become suicidal, we could not love and have faith
- without faith/belief/trust (all the same word in the Greek, a person cannot function in the real world and cannot believe anything about the invisible God, we could not love and have hope
- without love the world, even this wicked world would cease to function and we would loose hope and could not have faith.

Thus, the trio of virtues, as documented above, must all exist in the human spirit together.  There are numerous passages that rehearse the essential nature of each of these as Paul ably says.

**FAITH/BELIEF/TRUST** - The New Testament contains the phrase “faith/trust in Jesus” (“pistis en Iesous”) and in all cases the phrase is used as the basis for the Christian life and/or a cause for celebration and note by others.  Gal 3:26, Eph 1:15, Col 1:4, 1 Tim 1:14, 3:13, 2 Tim 1:13, 3:15, Heb 11:6.  No wonder we are told that without faith it is impossible to please God because we could not even understand that he exists!

**HOPE** - Without hope, humans become sick and ultimately, suicidal (Prov 13:12, 1 Chron 29:15, Job 17:15).  That is, hope is an essential part of being human and no one can function without hope; and Christ is our Great Hope!  1 Tim 1:1, 2 Tim 1:1, Titus 1:1, 2, Col 1:27, 1 Peter 1:3-6, Ps 147:11, 1 Cor 15:54-58.

**LOVE** - The best definition of agape love is, “God so loved … that He gave His son …” (John 3:16).  The “agape” love is the central most important characteristic, the very essence, of God (1 John 4:8, 16).  Love’s outward manifestation is grace.  It is God as love that defines God and all else about Him such as justice/righteousness tempered with kindness.

This principled love of God (1 John 4:8, 16) is to be imitated by all Christians (John 13:34, 35) and is motivated by God’s love for us (1 John 4:9, 10, 19-21, 2 Cor 5:14).  Thus, love is quintessentially Christian and reached its zenith when God gave Jesus as the solution to the sin problem (2 Cor 5:14, Eph 2:4, 3:19, 5:2, John 3:16).  Therefore, Christians should have as their primary focus their love of, and love to God (Matt 22:37, Deut 6:5), and secondarily love to fellow humans (Matt 22:39, Lev 19:18).

Thus, all three, faith/trust, hope and love are all essential - all are required for the others to exist at all.  "... *but the greatest of these is love*." (1 Cor 13:13).

Answer (score 0):

Dottard's answer is definitive. Here, I'll supplement a little.

1 Cor 13:

> 13 And now these three remain: faith, hope, and love; but the greatest of these is love.

All three are essential. Comparatively speaking, love is the greatest.

1 Corinthians 13:

> 2 And if I have prophetic powers, and understand **all** mysteries and **all** knowledge, and if I have **all** faith, so as to remove mountains, but have not love, I am **nothing**.

The "all" "all" "all" and "noting" indicate hypobole. It isn't all or nothing. It is comparative and relative.